# Using SlowCheetah's app.config transformations with Setup projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, app-config, setup-project, slowcheetah

I'm using the [SlowCheetah XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) extension to handle web.config-like transformations with app.config. That part works great.

I added a setup project and configured it to include the project output of the first project. I noticed that when I ran the installer, it installed the non-transformed app.config. Looking at the Primary output Outputs (say that 10 times fast), I noticed that its finding the binary in `Project\bin\Debug\Project.exe`, but `Project.exe.config` comes from `Project\app.config` instead of `Project\bin\Debug\Project.exe.config`.

I could exclude app.config from the Primary output, and hard-code the path to a specific configuration's app.config (`Project\bin\Debug\Project.exe.config`), but then I'd get the same app.config regardless of which configuration I used to build it.

Is there a workaround for getting the appropriate transformed app.config in a Setup project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi we are planning on releasing a new version which has ClickOnce support in the next few days. If you need a build of the add in before than which has the fix please contact me and I can get that out to you.

Comment: I just posted a new version, can you try it out?

Comment: The latest version works great, thanks! One thing that's a little confusing though, is that the extension says its version 2.0, but the [download page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) change history says 1.3.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the download page to state 2.0

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly the answer you're looking for but I have previously wrestled with how to get the correct app.config file into a setup project. I have a TFSBuild.proj msbuild file that uses transforms. The SlowCheetah transforms I think use the same msbuild task but I may be incorrect. SlowCheetah certainly provides a more useful user experience when working with transform files. My build file takes a slightly different approach. At the end of the automated build I wanted to generate installers for each of the target deployment environments. I use a number of msbuild extensions, including the *TransformXml* build task - not all required for the following but FWIW these are the imports:

```
<!-- import extensions -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
       AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
```

I have the following environments defined:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- target deployment environments -->
  <Configs Include="Prod" />
  <Configs Include="Staging" />
  <Configs Include="Test" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then the standard *AfterCompileSolution* target contains a call to the target that generates the installer for each environment:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompileSolution">

  <!-- Create installers for target deployment environments -->
  <CallTarget Targets="MyProject" />

</Target>

<Target Name="MyProject" Outputs="%(Configs.Identity)">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyProjectTempConfig Include="$(SolutionRoot)\MyProjectService\Temp.config" />
    <MyProjectConfigFrom Include="$(SolutionRoot)\MyProjectService\App.%(Configs.Identity).config" />
    <MyProjectConfigTo Include="$(SolutionRoot)\MyProjectService\App.config">
      <Attributes>ReadOnly</Attributes>
    </MyProjectConfigTo>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="MyProject - Target environment: %(Configs.Identity)" />

  <!-- transform app.config using appropriate -->
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyProjectConfigTo)"
        DestinationFiles="@(MyProjectTempConfig)"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
        ContinueOnError="true"
        Condition="!Exists(@(MyProjectTempConfig))"/>

  <File TaskAction="RemoveAttributes" Files="@(MyProjectConfigTo)"/>

  <TransformXml Source="@(MyProjectTempConfig)"
                Transform="@(MyProjectConfigFrom)"
                Destination="@(MyProjectConfigTo)" />

  <!-- run setup -->
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv&quot; &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\MyProject.sln&quot; /build Release /project MyProjectService.Setup"/>

  <!-- rename output for target deployment environment -->
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionRoot)\MyProjectService.Setup\Release\MyProjectService.msi"
        DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\%(Configs.Identity)_MyProjectService.msi"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
        ContinueOnError="true"/>

</Target>
```